# I use objImporter it is not problem created unity but i import created 3dmax it is problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I use objImporter it is not problem created unity but i import created 3dmax it is problem

사용한 스크립트
 https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ObjImporter

This error occured

```
Mesh.vertices is too large. A mesh may not have more than 65000 vertices.
UnityEngine.Mesh:set_vertices(Vector3[])
ObjImporter:ImportFile(String) (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/ObjImporter.cs:52)
UIManager:Load() (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Mesh.uv is out of bounds. The supplied array needs to be the same size as the Mesh.vertices array.
UnityEngine.Mesh:set_uv(Vector2[])
ObjImporter:ImportFile(String) (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/ObjImporter.cs:53)
UIManager:Load() (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Mesh.normals is out of bounds. The supplied array needs to be the same size as the Mesh.vertices array.
UnityEngine.Mesh:set_normals(Vector3[])
ObjImporter:ImportFile(String) (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/ObjImporter.cs:54)
UIManager:Load() (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Failed setting triangles. Some indices are referencing out of bounds vertices. IndexCount: 166833, VertexCount: 0
UnityEngine.Mesh:set_triangles(Int32[])
ObjImporter:ImportFile(String) (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/ObjImporter.cs:55)
UIManager:Load() (at Assets/MyAssets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Comment: It seems the model you use is too big to load, try some simple object (like cube) to test your code.

Comment: i used  scirpt use to cube it was no probelm

Comment: Well `A mesh may not have more than 65000 vertices.` .. your model is to complex. Certain 3D formats (e.g. .step and probably also .3ds) are really huge if converted to OBJ and containing any rounded parts .. you have to reduce it manually or use a program to reduce the geometry.

Comment: i drag objfile int project window that has not error but this scirpt has error two implementing are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the script uses meshes with 16 bit indices, which only support models up to the size of 2^16 vertices. Unity however supports 32 bit indices which supports up to 2^32 vertices = ~4 billion. All you should need to do is add this line:

```
mesh.indexFormat = Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
```

After this:

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
```

Inside the function `ImportFile`.

Note that some mobile devices do not support 32 bit indices.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html

Comment: Great! Consider marking it as the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem related to the model size, because the mesh may have more than 65000 vertices. you should read each chunk of 65000 vertices and put them in a mesh peice then collect all the mesh pieces in one mesh which is the sharedmesh,
i highly recommend use this asset [Simple .OBJ](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/simple-obj-22195), it will save your time